# Optional fields in Hibernate Mapping file

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to have optional fields in hibernate mapping file?
For some set of data I have a particular field and for others I don't have it.

For example

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="class1" >
<id name="id" column="id"/>
<property name="field1" column="field1"/>
<property name="field2" column="field2"/>
<property name="optionalfield" column="optionalfield"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The optionalfield might or might not be present. I am using two different queries on the same java class. Is it possible to map the fields to the same class in Hibernate?

Comment: That makes no sence. A class represents a table and the table has a column or not

Comment: you can have a `@Transient` annotated field actually but i dont know how to represent it via `xml`.

Comment: Why would you require it? If its optional or reserved for future use , your code should handle it in a manner that null goes always in it.right?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe i am not doing it the right way then! Here I am not mapping db tables to java classes, but mapping the data returned by join query to the java class.